# Counting how many rows contain chinese in mixed value dataset using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm wanting to count how often Chinese is used, I've tried langdetect but the issue is the values are a mix of numbers, text and even URLs which langdetect doesn't seem to support

```
import pandas as pd
from langdetect import detect

df = pd.read_csv("annotation_sample.csv", nrows=10)
df = df.drop(['id', 'profile_id', 'created', 'document_id'], axis=1)
df = df[pd.notnull(df['txt'])]
df

df.txt.apply(lambda x: detect(x))
```

Above works (although I've not figured out how to count a specific language) although it only works as its limited to 10 rows, when using the entire 10,000 it throws the 'No features in text' error

Pic of the data:

[image: pic of data]

What I need help with is;
How do I avoid running this on rows that contain just numbers, urls etc? Is there a way to skip error'd ones and continue?

Secondly, how do I then count how many have come back as a specific language?

Answer (score 1):

That should be feasible using some more python and pandas features:
- errors can be caught when you wrap the detect in your own function and return None (or what you prefer) instead of a language code
- results of the detect can be added to the df and counted, filtered, you name it.

```
def mydetect(txt):
    try:
        return detect(txt)
    except:
        return None
```

Pandas allows you to add the results to a second column of the dataframe, but I do not have the command handy at the moment, please check a tutorial.
Then you can filter the dataset or count occurences of a language.

You can also limit the except clause to certain errors if you think that would make more sense.